# Extract csv from google sheet to dropbox

Tags: csv, google-sheets, synchronization, dropbox

Is there a way to extract data from google sheet's work sheet, to a specific dropbox folder, in CSV format? Additionally, previously created CSV file must be re-written / replaced whenever new data is added to work sheet. Basically, I need a one-way sync from sheet to a CSV file in a dropbox folder.

Comment: About your question of `Is there a way to extract data from google sheet's work sheet, to a speciffic dropbox folder, in CSV format? Additionaly, previosly created CSV file must be re-written / replaced whenever new data is added to work sheet`, I think that when Dropbox API and Google Apps Script are used, your goal will be able to be achieved.

Comment: Yeah, I guess... But how do I do that? I'm not very familiar with App Script. I have tried to Google for possible solutios. There are some third party softwares, which are a bit sketchy and probably not at all necessary.

Comment: Might be easiest to see if IFTTT (if this then that) or Zapier supports this if you don't want to learn the APIs.  Maybe start here: https://ifttt.com/applets/zbaQ2TVk-save-your-google-docs-to-dropbox

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.